# Search with pagination using jquery

Tags: jquery, search, pagination

I creating custom search using jquery i want to show search result data with pagination of ul li here is my HTML

```
div id="test-list">
    <input type="text" class="search" />
    <ul class="list">
      <li><div class="abc">Guybrush Threepwood</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Elaine Marley</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">LeChuck</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Stan</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Voodoo Lady</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Herman Toothrot</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Meathook</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Carla</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Otis</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Rapp Scallion</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Rum Rogers Sr.</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Men of Low Moral Fiber</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Murray</div></li>
      <li><div class="abc">Cannibals</div></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
```

Pagination look like in this image

[image]

I am using this [list search](http://www.listjs.com/examples/pagination)

Comment: And what is the exact problem you are facing? Where is your jquery code?

Comment: when search any thing our pagination is updated but next,prev button links are not wrok